# SCP from remote network - finding address of local network

Tags: scp, remote

I'm trying to copy data from a remote server (university) to my local machine via scp

I know the basic command

```
username1@source_host:directory1/filename1 username2@destination_host:directory2/filename2
```

But I don't know how to specify (i.e find) the path I need for my local machine... How can I find that?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to scp file to your local machine, you don't need to specify path for the `destination_host` you have in your command.

Simply do

```
scp username1@source_host:directory1/filename1 /path/on/your/local/machine/
```

where `/path/on/your/local/machine/` is actually on your local machine, for instance `/home/user/Documents/`.

See [scp man](https://linux.die.net/man/1/scp) for reference, or this [tutorial](https://www.tecmint.com/scp-commands-examples/).

Answer (score 1):

Once you logged onto the remote server you can query how you got there, to use the information for `scp`.

```
scp filename localuser@$(echo $SSH_CONNECTION|awk '{print $1}'):Downloads
```